# How to print a inherit view

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

I would like to print a view on asset management. The name of class is `account.asset.asset`. This is a view that calculates the depreciation of assets. Someone can help me? Thanks you

Comment: Can you give more information ?

Comment: print a view do you mean a report?